# CoreML classification fails when model is converted from Keras to CoreML with multiple class_labels

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, coreml, coremltools

I am trying to make a model for an iOS app I'm working on. I train it using Keras. Then convert it to CoreML using coremltools.

When training it knows that I have two classes: cats and dogs. 
And it trains fine. After that I convert it and pass class_labels as a list: `["cat", "dog"]`. In app it doesn't work.

Shows an error: `"The VNCoreMLTransform request failed"`. If I leave only one `class_label` it works fine and classifies as well.

I am trying to figure out where I did something wrong.

Keras:

```
img_width, img_height = 224, 224

train_data_dir = 'data/train'
validation_data_dir = 'data/validate'
nb_train_samples = 1000
nb_validation_samples = 20
epochs = 10
batch_size = 10

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first': 
    input_shape = (3, img_width, img_height) 
else: 
    input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3) 

model = Sequential() 
model.add(Conv2D(32, (2, 2), input_shape = input_shape)) 
model.add(Activation('relu')) 
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size =(2, 2))) 

model.add(Conv2D(32, (2, 2))) 
model.add(Activation('relu')) 
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size =(2, 2))) 

model.add(Conv2D(64, (2, 2))) 
model.add(Activation('relu')) 
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size =(2, 2))) 

model.add(Flatten()) 
model.add(Dense(64)) 
model.add(Activation('relu')) 
model.add(Dropout(0.5)) 
model.add(Dense(1)) 
model.add(Activation('sigmoid')) 

model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', 
                optimizer = 'rmsprop', 
                metrics = ['accuracy']) 

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator( 
                rescale = 1. / 255, 
                 shear_range = 0.2, 
                  zoom_range = 0.2, 
            horizontal_flip = True) 

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1. / 255) 

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_data_dir, 
                              target_size =(img_width, img_height), 
                     batch_size = batch_size, class_mode ='binary') 

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory( 
                                    validation_data_dir, 
                   target_size =(img_width, img_height), 
          batch_size = batch_size, class_mode ='binary') 

model.fit_generator(train_generator, 
    steps_per_epoch = nb_train_samples // batch_size, 
    epochs = epochs, validation_data = validation_generator, 
    validation_steps = nb_validation_samples // batch_size) 

model.save('model_saved.h5')
```

Converter:

```
converted_model = coremltools.converters.keras.convert('model_saved.h5', 
                                                        input_names = 'image',
                                                        image_input_names = 'image',
                                                        output_names=['classLabelProbs'],
                                                        class_labels = ['cat', 'dog'])

#converted_model = coremltools.converters.keras.convert("model.h5")                  
converted_model.save('myModel.mlmodel')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the CoreML converter is not aware that binary classification can mean one output neuron that can represent two labels, so I think you have two options:

- Remove the class labels parameter and let the model output a single value, and then you do some post-processing to transform the model output to class labels (setting a threshold too).
- You train a binary classification model with two output neurons and `softmax` activation, which should work fine with the CoreML converter and your class labels.

Comment: Sorry for late answerm been wrapped up in work. I dont know how would I do the first step so I focused on the other one. I am new to keras so my question would be how would I go with setting two output neurons when training my model. For reference I used this guide and the code from it: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-image-classification-using-keras/ I changed only the save_weights to just save as I cant convert the weights only to coreML.

Answer (score 0):

I faced to same problem and finally could figure out a solution by my own.

1. **2** units of `Dense` and `softmax` activation

```
.
.
.
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
.
.
```

2. Either `binary_crossentropy` or `categorical_crossentropy`

```
model.compile(..... loss='binary_crossentropy'.....)
```

good luck!